# Breakpoints using clang and Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb, clang

I have a C++ project which I built using g++. I tried to switch to clang++. The program compiles and runs fine. However, in Eclipse, breakpoints do not work anymore. I tried to build using

```
clang++ -ggdb -O2
```

to ensure that gdb specific symbols are generated.

The OS is Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, clang is version 3.4-1ubuntu3, and Eclipse is version Mars (C++ Edition with cdt).

Comment: Try compiling without optimization.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it ! Debug now takes a long time, I might have a look at lldb ...